# Pass hidden value from database when Using autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am suing autocomplete to display values from database.
The file is as follows:

autocomplete.php

```
  <?php
    require_once "../includes/conf.php";
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
//$mysqli=mysql_connect('localhost','root','','autofield') or die("Database Error");
$sql="SELECT vName,id FROM employee WHERE vName LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY vName";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if($result)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['vName']." </n>".$row['id'];

    }
}
  ?>
```

The above file retuens the name that will be displayed in the text filed. Along with that I would like to pass id as hidden field so that I can process the data in php

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of input type hidden for this purpose.

```
<input type="hidden" value=".$row['id']."/>
```

Comment: before this try `print_r($row);` to see how the array is populated

Comment: yes directly in above code.but you will need to echo the input tag!!

Comment: And how would I retrieve it in the other page then?

Comment: you will get the value stored in the database.and you can retrieve that value from the database on any page you want to.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$array = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($array ,array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['vName']));
}
```

and in jquery code:

```
terms.push( ui.item.label );
$( "#hidtextboxid" ).val( ui.item.value);
```

make sure you create one hidden field in your code.

check this:
[how to pass hidden id using json in jquery ui autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200964/how-to-pass-hidden-id-using-json-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

i dont want to answer your question with `mysql_query` for two reasons:

**1.** mysql_query official status is Deprecated: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

**2.** it is vulnerable to SQL injection, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

use PDO (PHP Data Objects ) instead, it is secured and it is object-oriented
here are some tutorials to master this in 12 videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQjKkNiByCk

replace your MySQL instance with this

```
// instance of pdo
$config['db'] = array
(
    'host' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => ''
);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . 
';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'],
$config['db']['username'],
$config['db']['password']);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
global $dbh;
```

//dbh is just a custom name for the object you can name it database

edit the credentials, next lets query your code, if the instance is not on the same file ie the connection script is being included then call upon `global $dbh;` before you start your sql so you bring the object to the current file otherwise

so your code will look like this

```
<?php

global $dbh;
//lets prepare the statement using : to input what ever variables we need to (securely)
$displayData= $dbh->prepare("SELECT vName,id FROM employee WHERE vName LIKE :my_data ORDER BY vName");
    $displayData->bindValue(':my_data', $my_data , PDO::PARAM_STR); 
//then we execute the code
    $displayData->execute();
//store the result in array
    $result = $displayData->fetchAll();
 print_r($result); //take a look at the structured

//depending on the structure echoing could be like **echo $result[0][theIdYouTrynaGet];**

?>
```

**And how would I retrieve it in the other page then?**

```
<html>
<?php  
include_once '/*the path of your file where the above is happening*/';
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result['pass in your parameters'] ?>"/>
?>
<html>
```